# Условие, чтобы рандомные числа не повторялись

Tags: java

Выборка символов. Данный метод заключатся в том, что  от пользователя при обращении к системе не требуется полного  указания пароля, а лишь его части. В этом случае ему задается вопрос по инициативе ЭВМ и при правильном ответе  на  него  осуществляется доступ к системе. Причем ЭВМ каждый раз запрашивает разные символы, например: Пароль: `«Караганда»`. Вопрос ЭВМ: `Назовите 3-й и 5-й символы пароля`.
Ответ пользователя: `рг . . .` Вопрос ЭВМ: `Назовите 1-й и 7-й символы пароля`. Ответ пользователя: `кн`

Преимущество метода: исключается возможность случайного  «подсматривания» пароля и усложняется процесс преднамеренного отгадывания.

Недостаток: необходимость  разработки  дополнительных  программных средств, позволяющих реализовать процедуру формирования вопросов (например, с использованием генератора случайных чисел).

Код:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public Main(String s) {
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s="12345678912";
    String l;
    String l1;
    String j;
    String j1;
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int r1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println(r+" және "+r1+" рындағы символдарды енгізіңіз:");
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        l = scan.nextLine();
        j=s.substring(r-1,r);

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        l1 = scan1.nextLine();
        j1=s.substring(r1-1,r1);

        if (j.equals(l)&&j1.equals(l1)) {
            System.out.println("пароль правильно!!!");
            break;

        } else {
            System.out.println("введен неправильный пароль!!! Повторите попытку");
        }
    }

}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги, не ругайтесь на человека за "числы" и т.п. Очевидно, что для него русский язык не родной.

По поводу вопроса. Действительно, может так случится, что машина сгенерирует вам два одинаковых числа. Поэтому генерацию чисел стоит поместить в цикл с проверкой. Например, так:

```
int r = 0, r1 = 0;
boolean areSame = true;

while (areSame) {
    r = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    r1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    areSame = r == r1;
}
```